# Is there a nice criterion for when translation acts on conjugacy classes in a $p$-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, and let $a\in G$. Certainly translation-by-$a$ determines an automorphism of $G$ (as a set).

Is there a nontrivial criterion for when translation-by-$a$ descends to a well-defined automorphism of the set of conjugacy classes of $G$?

Ie, for which $a\in G$ is it true that for all $g,h\in G$, we have that $ag$ is conjugate to $ahgh^{-1}$?

Certainly any $a\in Z(G)$ has this property, but this is true for all groups. Can we do better (perhaps by using properties of $p$-groups)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a$ has that property, then $e=aa^{-1}$ is conjugate to $aha^{-1}h^{-1}$ for all $h$.

Comment: Ah, good point. I guess the center is the best we can do. Thanks!